# Approximate regular expression library for Java?

Tags: java, regex, approximate

I have just written some code for approximate string matching. I would like to benchmark my naive algorithm against a more mature implementation running on the JVM. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is "approximate" a technical term I've never heard of, or is your code just "approximately correct" ?

Comment: If this is for bioinformatics, you're reinventing some complicated wheels.

Comment: @Carl Smotricz 
By approximate I mean to say that the two strings are approximately matched if they are within a certain edit distance of one another. See, for example, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching.

Comment: @msw- Yes, I am trying to learn some things about biological sequence alignment by attacking some canonical (and fun) problems. I don't expect my hack will be competitive with state of the art alignment programs. However, I am curious to see how badly it fails. At any rate, if you do know of a good Java library, I would love to hear about it.

Comment: This has been an educational experience for me, thanks! I've tried to include at least a little bit of useful information in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found these answers elsewhere on this site for similar problems.

> Commons Lang has an implementation of Levenshtein distance.
>  
>   http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html
>
> Commons Codec has an implementation of soundex and metaphone.
>  
>   http://commons.apache.org/codec/api-release/org/apache/commons/codec/language/Soundex.html
>  
>   http://commons.apache.org/codec/api-release/org/apache/commons/codec/language/Metaphone.html

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327513/fuzzy-string-search-in-java))

> Lucene (http://lucene.apache.org/) also implements Levenshtein edit distance.

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309479/how-to-find-best-fuzzy-match-for-a-string-in-a-large-string-database): zarawesome)

Comment: Thanks, Gunslinger. The Levenshtein distance from StringUtils will be useful for a direct performance comparison.

Answer (score 0):

It so happens I reinvented this wheel many years ago - in a FORTRAN program on a mainframe :)

When I proudly told other people on the Internet about my algorithm, they laughed and pointed me at the two (four?) big names in this area:

- [Needleman-Wunsch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman%E2%80%93Wunsch_algorithm) and
- [Smith-Waterman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Waterman_algorithm).

These are algorithms for comparing huge sequences of similar strings. Memory requirement is about `m + n`, where m and n are the sizes of the strings, and runtime is about `m * n`.

Gunslinger47 mentions Levenshtein, Soundex and Metaphone. Levenshtein is also a powerful means of computing string distances, but it's better suited for "normal" text. Soundex and Metaphone compute a short string intended to encode the sound of the string when spoken by a human... they become ineffective after about 3 syllables, they're really intended for words in human language rather than strings of genomes or such.

**EDIT**

Oops, I just found my 4 big names at the bottom of the article you cited. So you're already aware of them. I think that if you search for those names and "Java" should find you implementations. [Here's the first one I found](http://www25.brinkster.com/denshade/NeedlemanWunsch.java.htm).